# Backing up uploaded document on Linux

Tags: php, linux, backup, cron

So I have a PHP application running on linux machine which is using a mysql database. I have manage to add the back up my mysql database every day by adding a code in the CRONTAB. In my application clients are able to upload document, of which a saved in a directory in the application folder `ie /myapp/uploaded_documents/`, I am looking at backing up this directory.

My question is: how do I back up a directory to a certain remote location on a certain time every day? Is it possible to also password protect this directory on my app folder?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use rsync, as you would be uploading (most likely) changes only.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

Additionally you can create incremental backup:

http://www.mikerubel.org/computers/rsync_snapshots/

So my suggested solution would be rsync + crontab

Answer (score 1):

As told in previous answer, to backup periodically on a remote machine you can use rsync+ssh+crontab. Just set ssh to access the remote machine without password following (for ubuntu distro) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys, then add to crontab a rsync job at the time and days you want (check man crontab to understand how to do this), telling rsync to backup over ssh on a remote machine, something like `0 2 * * * rsync -ae ssh dir_to_bkp name@host:dir_where_bkp` to backup each day at 02:00 am the "dir_to_bkp" in the "host" machine using "name" user and "dir_where_bpk" as destination. The -e ssh option in rsync specify to use ssh.